# How can I place descriptive text next to each image in Colorbox?

Tags: colorbox

I would like to display descriptive text, next to each image in a Colorbox gallery. I can give sufficient width to get me space around the image using the colorbox parameter 'width' and change some CSS to get the space to the left of the image. Now, I want to place text in the white space. All the content is generated dynamically but that does not matter for this question as the colorbox code itself is generated using PhP. 
Any ideas of doing this without changing the colorbox JS code?

Comment: Please provide some code, show the attempts what you have done. visit this link - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The code is a bit ugly as I am just experimenting in bits and pieces. I finally got a div to be "attached" to the colorbox whose content is populated based on the image position in the set. That constitutes my comments for the image. The div moves with the colorbox so I had to get the top, left pos of the colorbox. Problem is that the top,left positions are back by one! I mean the first time, colorbox opens with a size that has nothing to do with the first image to be displayed. May be this is a colorbox bug? If I can get that fixed, I would be set!